# clicking on image using selenium webdriver java?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on mage which is in a table cell, image doesnot have id, classname etc.
The img html is:

```
img src="/Framework/images/moredetails.gif"
```

I am using the below CSS path:

```
html body div#minwidth div#outer_wrapper div#wrapper div#container div#content div#main div.maincontentarea div#top_contentbox div#top_tablewrapperdivtab form div#AddEdit response div.contentbox1 div.contentbox div#Accepted.tablewrapperdivtab div.scrolldiv div#AcceptedDetails table.tablelist tbody#detailBody tr td img
```

I tried with xpath:

```
//*[@id='detailBody']/tr[1]/td[16]/img
```

I don't want to go with the above xpath, since in future if the cell no. is changed, again xpath needs to be changed. Is their any best way to handle the above??

Comment: am not able to add html content to ny que, its saying error in submission..!!!

Comment: img src="/Framework/images/moredetails.gif"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the xpath below :

`"//img[contains(@src,'/TCSFramework/images/moredetails.gif')]"`

For all `img` tag, you'll take the one that has "/TCSFramework/images/moredetails.gif" in his `src` value.

---

Many images withe the same src ? No problemo.

You can build a list with all your img like :

```
List<WebElement> listImg = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'/TCSFramework/images/moredetails.gif')]"));
```

after getting all your `img`, if you know what his position order (in the html) like

```
<img> position 0 </img>
<img> position 1 </img> <----- you want that img
<img> position 2 </img>
```

you'll write something like (you get the img at position 1 and click on it)

```
listImg.get(1).click();
```

**But,** if you don't know his position order (in the html) you need to add condition in your xpath like if the name contains a specific value or the class is specific to the img.

Can you post your img html line? (if the probleme isn't resolved)

---

I've a cssSelector for you, try it and tell me what's up :

css : `"#detailBody tr:first-child td:nth-child(16) img"`

Comment: thanks for reply, but the prob is their are many images in the table, which contains same src.

Comment: img src=Framework/images/moredetails.gif
onclick=openFrame /jsp/templates/stock/GRN/ub/popUpBatchNumber.jsp?entityType=popupGRNBatchNumber&amp;amp;specificationType=machine&amp;amp;action=createcreate&amp;amp;sno=0 ,'Batch Number List'

Comment: Hiii, ive posted the html content with sme modifications to avoid the submission error.